# JavaScript newbie trying to filter out a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, nginx

I have a nginx directory with files in it, I'm trying to implement a search so people can search for files. I found https://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2/ on this site, and I tried replicating it over at https://jsfiddle.net/a95odpcd/ but it doesn't to be working very well.

I think the problem lies here, but I am not very sure:

```
   var $rows = $('#list tr');
```

I've been trying to get it working for a few hours now, trying every possible thing I can think of. Is there anybody who knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing jquery you can include it using Frameworks and extension.

[image]